# How to reorder column values ascending order that are seperated by "," and only keep first value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a column in a df that consists of values like so:

```
ID
2
NA
1
3
4
5,7
9,6,10
12
15
16
17
NA
19
22,23
```

I would like to reorder every row based on ascending order. Note - this column is a "character" based field and some rows are already in the correct order.

From there, I only want to keep the first value and remove the others.

### Desired output:

```
ID
2
NA
1
3
4
5
6
12
15
16
17
NA
19
22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the data on comma, `sort` them and extract the 1st value.

```
df$ID <- sapply(strsplit(df$ID, ','), function(x) sort(as.numeric(x))[1])

#   ID
#1   2
#2  NA
#3   1
#4   3
#5   4
#6   5
#7   6
#8  12
#9  15
#10 16
#11 17
#12 NA
#13 19
#14 22
```

---

A couple of `tidyverse` alternatives.

```
library(tidyverse)

#1.
#Same as base R but in tidyverse
df %>% mutate(ID = map_dbl(str_split(ID, ','), ~sort(as.numeric(.x))[1]))

#2.
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(ID, sep = ',', convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(ID = min(ID)) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another tidyverse solution: Making use of (`dyplr`, `purrr`, `stringr` and `readr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(ID = map_chr(str_split(ID, ","), ~ 
                           toString(sort(as.numeric(.x)))),
           ID = parse_number(ID))
)
```

output:

```
   ID
1   2
2  NA
3   1
4   3
5   4
6   5
7   6
8  12
9  15
10 16
11 17
12 NA
13 19
14 22
```

Answer (score 3):

We may use the `min`imum instead of sorting / extracting:

```
DF <- transform(DF, ID=sapply(strsplit(ID, ','), \(x) min(as.double(x))))
DF
#    ID
# 1   2
# 2  NA
# 3   1
# 4   3
# 5   4
# 6   5
# 7   6
# 8  12
# 9  15
# 10 16
# 11 17
# 12 NA
# 13 19
# 14 22
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(ID = as.numeric(str_extract(ID, '\\d+')))
```

-output

```
   ID
1   2
2  NA
3   1
4   3
5   4
6   5
7   9
8  12
9  15
10 16
11 17
12 NA
13 19
14 22
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("2", NA, "1", "3", "4", "5,7", "9,6,10", 
"12", "15", "16", "17", NA, "19", "22,23")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```